# How to get a class's pointer in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class

If I declared a class in a controller and want to use it in a model without passing the class' pointer, how can I redeclare that class without the "Fatal error: Class already declared"? If I use the [get_declared_classes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) function, I see that the class is declared, but how can I get the pointer to that class so that I can use it in the model?

Basically, how can I use a class that's been declared but with no pointer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Maybe the word "pointer" was misused. Here's some code

```
// Controller...one file
$class = new Class();
$model = $this->load_model('example.php');
$model->dosomething();

// Model...example.php
function dosomething() {
    // I want to access the class here. Is it only possible to do this by
    // passing a $class parameter to the function or can I do it without
    // passing it as a variable?
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "class pointer"? PHP has no concept of "class pointers", only instance pointers/references. Any example pseudo-PHP code?

Comment: could you provide some more information what you want to do with that class? if you just want to instantiate it `$class = new Classname();` ?

Comment: Do keep in mind, that the concepts from one set of languages are not necessarily boltable to another.

Comment: *Classes*, once declared, can be used from anywhere within the app. Please give us some concrete example in code.

Comment: After update: You want to access a **class instance** a.k.a. **an object** inside the function, not a *class*. This is a simple question about variable scopes and/or design patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're mixing terminology.  There's no concept of a pointer anywhere in PHP.  References are similar concepts, but that's another topic.

What I think you're trying to do, is use a variable to indicate the class in the model.  So, you can use a string.  So let's say you want to tell the model to use class `Foo`, you could inject the class name into the model:

```
$model = new Model('foo');
```

Then, inside the constructor:

```
public function __construct($class) {
    $this->className = $class;
}
```

Then, when you want to use it, just call `new`:

```
$class = $this->className;
$obj = new $class();
```

But note that it has nothing to do with object scope.  So you could do it anywhere:

```
$class = 'Foo';
$obj = new $class;
```